# Get Process Name for RPC Client

Tags: windows, rpc

Given an RPC call I can easily impersonate the client and get their process token, but how do I get the process name from that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the process name for an RPC client, you must use [RpcServerInqCallAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378434(v=vs.85).aspx) to query the process ID, [OpenProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320(v=vs.85).aspx) with the process ID to get the process handle, and [QueryFullProcessImageName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919(v=vs.85).aspx) with the process handle to get the full process name.